# Как увеличить количество рекурсивных вызовов?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

Для примера, я написал простую рекурсивную функцию, проводящую инкремент числа каждую итерацию. К сожалению, стандартного размера стека вызовов не хватает.

> Запускать браузер с специальным флагом командной строки не вариант - должно работать из коробки.

```
const recursive = () => {
    let acm = 0;
    const incrementor = () => incrementor(acm++);
    try {
        incrementor();
    } catch {
        console.log("Total: ", acm)
    }
}
recursive() // Total:  6966
```

Скажите пожалуйста, нет ли какого-либо полифила, позволяющего увеличить количество рекурсивных вызовов, пусть даже ценой потери производительности?

Comment: На что вы их тратите?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Поиск текста по файлу регулярным выражением

Comment: а зачем вам там рекурсия, можно же написать итеративный алгоритм, который не будет ограничен стеком и не будет проигрывать по производительности?

Comment: Так есть же формат исполнения регулярного выражения при котором вернутся все совпадения.

Comment: @ТрипольскийПётр а что мешает делать поиск циклом? Зачем тут рекурсия?

Comment: `console.log( ( str.match(/regex/ig) || [ ].length ) );` ?)